# Show that $B_0 \subset B_1$ for $B_j$ $:= \sigma(A_j)$ being a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let
>
> $A_0 :=$ $\{(a, b) : a, b \in \Bbb R\}$,
>
> $A_1 :=$ $\{(a, b] : a, b \in \Bbb R\}$.
>
> Show that
>
> $B_0 \subset B_1$
>
> for $B_j$ $:= \sigma(A_j)$ being a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am not quite sure how to tackle this problem. I understand it the following way:

$A_0$ is the set of every open space that exists on $\Bbb R$. $A_1$ is the set of every half-open space that exists on $\Bbb R$. Now, we define the $\sigma$-algebra, meaning that we construct sets $B_0$ and $B_1$ that contain elements of $P(A_0)$ and $P(A_1)$ (power set) and that possess the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra.

I tried to show the statement for the most simple case I could imagine with

$A \in B_0, A$ $:=$ $\{(a, b)\}$,

so $A$ is a set that contains exactly one open space $(a, b)$. Now, if I understood the task right, I have to show that $A$ is also an element of $B_1$, meaning that $B_1$, although defined on a set that only contains half-open spaces, also contains sets that contain open spaces like the one above.

So, maybe it would be possible by using the propertes of a $\sigma$-algebra for something like sets $\{(a, b]\}$ and $\{[b, c)\}$, but two problems arise with that:

Using the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra doesn't give me anything useful, for example $\{(a, b]\}$ $\cup$ $\{[b, c)\}$ just gives me an element that contains both of these intervals, but I don't see a way to construct a open set with that. Futhermore, I can't even be sure that the elements / intervals mentioned before are actually a part of $B_1$, can I? I mean, this would only hold if the $\sigma$-algebra was identical with the power set.

I'd be glad if someone could give me some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to show if $B_{0} = \sigma( \{ (a,b) \mid a, b \in \Bbb R \} )$ and $B_{1} = \sigma( \{ (a,b] \mid a, b \in \Bbb R \} )$, then $B_{0} \subseteq B_{1}$, where of course we are assuming $a \leq b$.

But $B_{0}$, which is defined as $\sigma( \{ (a,b) \mid a, b \in \Bbb R \} )$, is by definition **the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the intervals $(a,b)$**, right?  Since $B_{1}$ is another $\sigma$-algebra, then if we can show every interval $(a,b)$ is in $B_{1}$, then this necessarily implies $B_{0} \subseteq B_{1}$, since otherwise $B_{0} \cap B_{1}$ would be a smaller $\sigma$-algebra than $B_{0}$ containing the intervals $(a,b)$, a contradiction.  (Of course I'm using the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then so is $X \cap Y$ -- and this is something very easy to prove, and you should prove it yourself.)

So, let's show $(a,b) \in B_{1}$ for every interval $(a,b)$.  $B_{1}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the intervals $(a,b]$, so all of the intervals $(a,b]$ are in $B_{1}$.  If we could only express $(a,b)$ as maybe a countable union of $(c,d]$-type intervals, then since the $(c,d]$-type intervals are in $B_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ is closed under countable unions, we would get $(a,b)$ is in $B_{1}$.

Hmm, well, $(a,b) = \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$.  I am leaving this fact for you to prove.  Once you prove it, you can use it.

Okay, so since $(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$ is in $B_{1}$ for every $n$, and $(a,b)$ is the countable union of elements of $B_{1}$, that means $(a,b)$ is in $B_{1}$.  Then this implies $B_{0} \subseteq B_{1}$ by the reasoning I gave earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much, that should do the trick! This task goes even further, I'll have to show that $B_1 \subset B_2$,$ B_2 \subset B_3$ and $B_3 \subset B_0$ for $ A_2 $containing closed intervals on$ \Bbb R$ and $A_3$ containing half-open intervals ranging from $-\infty$ to $b$. I guess that works similar?

Comment: @Julian Yes, it works similarly!  For example, to show $B_{1} \subseteq B_{2}$, you need to show intervals like $(a,b]$ can be written as a countable union of $[c,d]$-type intervals.  Just take the union of $[a + \frac{1}{n}, b]$.  For $B_{2} \subseteq B_{3}$, we want to express $[a,b]$ as $(-\infty, d]$-type intervals.  This one is a bit more tricky.  The $(-\infty, d]$-type intervals have a right end point, but no left end point!  But you know $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complements, and if $(-\infty, d]$ has complement $(d,\infty)$, telling you that intervals of the form $(d,\infty)$

Comment: @Julian ...are in $B_{3}$.  Then for each $d$, $(d - \frac{1}{n}, \infty)$ is in $B_{3}$, so the **intersection** $\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (d-\frac{1}{n}, \infty)$ is in $B_{3}$.  But this intersection is just $[d,\infty)$ (prove that!), so intervals of the type $[d,\infty)$ are in $B_{3}$ too.  Finally, we can write $[a,b]$ as $[a,\infty) \cap (-\infty, b]$, and since each of these components is in $B_{3}$, so is their intersection, showing $[a,b] \in B_{3}$.  Finally, to show $B_{3} \subseteq B_{0}$, show every $(-\infty, d]$-type interval is in $B_{0}$...

Comment: Plus, what gives me the fact that the half-open intervals I need to perform the necessary unions are indeed in $B_1$? I understand that they have to be in $A_1$, of course, but wouldn't it be possible that $B_1$ doesn't contain these elements? Or does this contradict $B_1$ being a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Julian ...i.e., can be expressed in some way using intervals $(a,b)$ for $a$ and $b$ real numbers.  I'll leave this one for you to think about, but it's in the spirit of the others.

Comment: @Julian Do any of my previous comments answer your question?  If not, let me know (and please be a little more specific with your question). :)

Comment: I'll have a look at it first and try to understand it. Thanks for these amazing answers so far! :)

Comment: @Julian You're welcome!  Once you understand these answers fully, the approach to answering these questions will start to become clear to you and you'll start producing your own amazing answers!

Comment: I wonder: Was I wrong with assuming that $B_0$ contains elements like $\{(a, b)\}$? Because in your answer you only work with the specific intervals. I thought that a $\sigma$-algebra only contains subsets of the power set of $A_0$, therefore, an interval of the type $(a, b)$ can't be a part of $B_0$, but $\{(a, b)\}$ can.

Comment: @Julian No, you are right.  A $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets.  $(a,b)$ is a set, in particular a subset of $\Bbb R$.  So it is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $B_{0}$.  So we can write $(a,b) \in B_{0}$ or $\{ (a,b) \} \subseteq B_{0}$.  But we **wouldn't** write $\{ (a,b) \} \in B_{0}$ because if we did it would imply $B_{0}$ has as elements **sets of sets**.  $\{ (a,b) \}$ is the set which contains one element: the element it contains is the set $(a,b)$.

Comment: Solved all of it by now, thanks! :)

Comment: @Julian Excellent!